# React Router history.push() changed url but did not rendered components content

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying some stuff with React router but stuck on how to render another component after clicking on submit button of the form.

`index.tsx`

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom"
import { store, StoreContext } from "./app/stores/store"
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <App />
            </Router>
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

`App.tsx`

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link,
    Route,
    Switch,
} from "react-router-dom"

<Router>
    <Navbar />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route
                exact
                path="/profiles"
                component={UsersDashboard}
             />
            <Route
                path={`/profiles/:username`}
                component={UserProfile}
            />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
</Router>
```

Every route work just fine except `/login`. I expected that after I submitted `LoginForm`, it will redirect me to the `/profiles` component. But it didn't. The route url changed but `/profiles` components content did not render.

`loginForm.tsx`

```
import { history } from "../.."

export default function LoginForm() {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    })

    const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // login feature is implemented in my custom store API 
        // I used hisoty.push to redirect to /profiles after form is submitted
        login(values).then(() => history.push("/profiles"))
    }

    const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value,
        })
    }

   // some irrelevant code too long so I cut it

   return (
        <div className="login__form">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h2>Login</h2>
                {inputs.map(input => (
                    <FormTextInput
                        inputProps={input}
                        key={input.id}
                        {...input}
                        value={input.name}
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                ))}
                <Button content="Submit" positive />
            </form>
        </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need hook `useHistory` from 'react-router-dom' but not from package `'history'`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
const history = useHistory();
history.push(...);
```

Comment: It is my misunderstood about Router!! Thank you so much, you save me all day!